# Does a change in electric field cause a change in magnetic field, or do both just always happen together?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I'm taking an entry-level Physics class. From my understanding, a change in electric field does not "cause" a change in magnetic field, but rather, both just always happen together out of necessity. For example, for the electric field to change, a charged particle must have moved, which would create a magnetic field. It's not a causality; they just have to happen together.

Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding? Because now we are learning about light and this doesn't seem to work to explain electromagnetic waves.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct within the variant of EM theory where all fields are retarded, i.e. they are mathematically determined by state of some accelerated charge somewhere sometime in the past.

However, there are mathematically valid variants of EM theory where not all EM waves come from accelerated charged particles in the past, but some EM wave field may be "just there" in space, not determined by state of any charged particles; or part of EM wave field may be determined by state of charged particles in the future, not past (advanced EM waves coming in from infinity and collapsing on the particles). These are pretty obscure and usually not considered to be relevant, although it is hard/impossible to prove they don't exist.

The usual EM theory works only with retarded fields so your viewpoint is the most usual one.

Comment: Then how does light work? The teacher said that light is a chain reaction of electric field producing a magnetic field, then magnetic field producing electric field, etc., which forms what is called a EM wave. But this explanation wouldn't work if the relationship is not causality

Comment: The retarded time: $t_r=t-|r-r'|/c$ points back in time to source charges and currents (and their 1st derivatives) so that resultant radiation fields propagate at $c$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations

Comment: @JoeC. yes that is common "explanation" but notice that electric and magnetic field exist both at the same place and same time, or vanish both at the same place and the same time. There is no transformation of electric    field into magnetic field, they are either both present, or both vanish. So I prefer to describe this by words "electric and magnetic field are generated in the past by some accelerated electric charge" rather than "electric field is generated magnetic field and vice versa".